# Printing to stderr on cmd fails to print first character of non-ASCII UTF-8 text

Tags: c, windows, utf-8, printf, stderr

This is what my code looks like:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);

    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfie;
    ZeroMemory(&cfie, sizeof(cfie));
    cfie.cbSize = sizeof(cfie);
    lstrcpyW(cfie.FaceName, L"Lucida Console");
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hStdOut, 0, &cfie);

    fprintf(stderr, "нијe\n");
}
```

The output is this:

```
��ијe
```

When the printing line is substituted with: `printf("нијe\n");`

The output is the expected:

```
нијe
```

I should probably mention I compiled this with MinGW-GCC and ran it in CMD.

Comment: Don’t know much about the windows api, but it seem that you are setting up the winapi “stdout” equivalent. Still you are writing to “stderr”.

Comment: Whether it's stdout or stderr, your code shouldn't assume that the file is a console screen buffer. You should detect a screen buffer and adapt how you handle the file. The console is generally broken with UTF-8, especially prior to Windows 8. C `FILE` streams make this worse by buffering the stream and occasionally splitting a UTF-8 sequence across two writes, which the console does not support in any version of Windows.

Comment: Normally I would suggest using wide-character functions such as `wprintf` in combination with setting a console-type file to UTF-16 mode and all other type files to UTF-8 mode, e.g. `_setmode(_file(stderr), _O_U16TEXT)`. However, I don't know if the old system CRT (msvcrt.dll) that's used by MinGW supports switching to the console's wide-character API in UTF-16 mode. I think that's limited to newer releases of VC++. If that's the case, then for console I/O I'd suggest abandoning C standard I/O completely and directly using the console API, i.e. `WriteConsoleW` and `ReadConsoleW`

Answer (score 1):

The `SetConsoleOutputCP()` alone works for me. Even "Consolas" as font gives the right characters.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "нијe\n");
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    fprintf(stderr, "нијe\n");
}
```

I compile with [MinGW-W64's GCC 8.1.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/):

```
> gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic console.c -o console.exe
```

The OS is Windows 10 (1903), run in Command Prompt with this command lines:

```
> for %i in (850 1252 65001) do ( mode con cp select=%i & console.exe & mode con /status )
```

It produces this output (German locale, sorry):

```
> (mode con cp select=850   & console.exe   & mode con /status  )

Status von Gerät CON:
---------------------
    Zeilen:          9999
    Spalten:         120
    Wiederholrate:   31
    Verzögerungszeit:1
    Codepage:        850

ð¢ð©Ðÿe
нијe

Status von Gerät CON:
---------------------
    Zeilen:          9999
    Spalten:         120
    Wiederholrate:   31
    Verzögerungszeit:1
    Codepage:        850

> (mode con cp select=1252   & console.exe   & mode con /status  )

Status von Gerät CON:
---------------------
    Zeilen:          9999
    Spalten:         120
    Wiederholrate:   31
    Verzögerungszeit:1
    Codepage:        1252

Ð½Ð¸Ñ˜e
нијe

Status von Gerät CON:
---------------------
    Zeilen:          9999
    Spalten:         120
    Wiederholrate:   31
    Verzögerungszeit:1
    Codepage:        1252

> (mode con cp select=65001   & console.exe   & mode con /status  )

Status von Gerät CON:
---------------------
    Zeilen:          9999
    Spalten:         120
    Wiederholrate:   31
    Verzögerungszeit:1
    Codepage:        65001

нијe
нијe

Status von Gerät CON:
---------------------
    Zeilen:          9999
    Spalten:         120
    Wiederholrate:   31
    Verzögerungszeit:1
    Codepage:        65001
```

*Just a note: Use `STD_ERROR_HANDLE` instead of `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` if you want the handle of `stderr`.*

Comment: This is technically correct because in general stdout and stderr may reference different files. (By default they reference the same console screen buffer.) However, it's unrelated to the problem. The OP is only using the handle to modify the font of the screen buffer. That's irrelevant to "н" (U+043D) being written to the screen as "��", i.e. two replacement characters (U+FFFD).